Are there any implications of using a symbolic link or bind mount vs having the real files there?
I have an indirect wildcard autofs mount on home but would like a few local folders to remain in there.  Thus I moved those local folders elsewhere and created a bind mount.  As a backup, incase autofs dies, I created a symbolic link in /home to the folder as well.
This seems to work fine, however, before I push this configuration to the rest of the systems on my network, I'd like to know if there are any potential issues/drawbacks to doing this.  Is this opaque to software accessing the /home paths?  Or can this cause problems?
A workaround would be to leave the local folders there and manually have autofs do direct mounts for all the other home folders but it creates more work when adding/deleting accounts.
example, I want /home/local to remain so:
# mkdir /export
# mv /home/local /export/.
# ln -s /export/local /home/local

auto.master
...
/home auto.home

auto.home
local -bind :/export/local
* -fstype=nfs,rw,sync nfs-server:/home/&

when autofs is running, /home/local is available via the bind mount.  if autofs is down, it is available via the symbolic link.  I beleive any software using anything in /home/local should not know the differnce or be unaffected but I'm not 100% sure.  So my question, re the any disadvantages or implications?  This is really about symbolic links or bind mount vs the normal hard link.  The autofs reference is just for context.

Can you please edit your question and show us the setup? Perhaps an ls -l showing the dirs and the synlinks.

As Knuth said, debug code, not comments.  Please show us your config files and the directory contents, can't debug a description.

edited with config.  I'm not asking to debug anything

Some programs may treat symlinks differently from real files/dirs (which is what mounts appear as). E.g. they might not follow links when recursively walking a tree. Most simple programs that just pass the path to OS won't see a difference.

Interesting, can you elaborate on when this would happen?  (program treating symlink differently and not following)

When you access a file through a path with a symbolic link directory, the link (just a text string) is hopefully resolved as you access the file via this resolved path.  Once resolved (say to a regular file beyond the link) there is no issue.
However traversing that symbolic link is not precisely the same as traversing a directory.  Many tools like 'find', 'cp' and 'ls' won't recursively follow the symlink in the same way as a mountpoint without adding command line options.
I'd opt for bind, assuming you have root, and may apply some unspecified apps at some future date.

So bind mount will behave the same as if the regular file was there?  I don't understand your last sentence "and may apply some unspecified apps at some future date."

In my example, I only have the symlink to actual /home in case autofs dies.  I could do a bind mount instead but I'm unsure what happens when autofs mounts in top of home then creates another bind mount.  I suppose it should be ok

Last sentence means that you may use some script or application that doesn't handle directory symlinks as hoped for.  For example  'find' has "never follow symlinks" as the default.
